# Not executing on Mysql 5.1 version

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE "USERMASTER" 
(   
    "REGISTRATION_ID" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "USERMASTER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("REGISTRATION_ID") ENABLE
)
```

I am getting error while executing on mysql 5.1. Please give me solution.

Comment: That is DDL for Oracle, not for MySQL. The correct MySQL syntax is documented in the manual

Comment: You know, it would be quite helpful if you post the error you are getting...

Comment: Varchar2 is oracle datatype.

Comment: You want the statement in oracle or mysql?

Comment: in mysql....i changed varchar2..but still gettiong error

Comment: CREATE TABLE  "USERMASTER" 
   (    "REGISTRATION_ID" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "USERMASTER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("REGISTRATION_ID") ENABLE
   )  but stil gettng error as    (    "REGISTRATION_ID" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ENABLE, user at line 1

Comment: The MySQL identifier quote character is the backtick, not a double-quotation mark (unless the `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode is enabled).  MySQL does not have a `VARCHAR2` data type.  MySQL does not recognise the `ENABLE` field modifier.  See [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html).

Comment: anyone give me modified code please...

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html), the MySQL identifier quote character is the backtick, not a double-quotation mark (unless the `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode is enabled):

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```
>
> If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
> mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> ```

As documented under [String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-types.html), MySQL does not have a `VARCHAR2` data type:

> The string types are [`CHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/binary-varbinary.html), [`VARBINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/binary-varbinary.html), [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html), [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html), [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/enum.html), and [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html).

As documented under [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html), MySQL does not recognise the `ENABLE` field modifier:

> ```
> column_definition:
>     data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
>       [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
>       [COMMENT 'string']
>       [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
>       [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
>       [reference_definition]
> ```

Therefore, the equivalent syntax in MySQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE `USERMASTER`
(   
    `REGISTRATION_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    `USERNAME` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    `PASSWORD` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    `TYPE` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL, 
    `NAME` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT `USERMASTER_PK` PRIMARY KEY (`REGISTRATION_ID`)
)
```

Comment: thanku whts wrng in this syntax....  CREATE TABLE  'PERSONALDETAILS' 
   ( 'REGISTRATION_ID' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
 'NAME' VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
 'FATHERS_NAME' VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
 'AGE' VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 'GENDER' VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL , 
 'CONTACT_NO' varchar(12) NOT NULL, 
 'ALT-CONTACT_NO' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
 'EMAILID' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
 'ALT-EMAILID' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT 'PERSONALDETAILS_PK'PRIMARY KEY ('REGISTRATION_ID'), 
  CONSTRAINT 'PERSONALDETAILS_UK1' UNIQUE ('CONTACT_NO'), 
  CONSTRAINT 'PERSONALDETAILS_UK2' UNIQUE ('EMAILID') 
   )